# Online IMAP client with Gmail support?

Tags: email, cloud-service, email-client, gmail, imap

I swear I tried looking everywhere and I can't find anything like this. I am trying to find an online webmail app, which would let me connect several accounts and check them in one place - pretty much just like any regular desktop client does.

The features I'm looking for:

- full Gmail support (including labels)
- IMAP support
- ideally should also sync Google Calendar

I've found some possible solutions, but none of them really cut it.

I know I can import IMAP accounts into my Gmail - but it's not perfect. Furthermore, I cannot import permanently another Gmail account but instead I have add it every time I want to access it.

Several open-source webmail clients were also tested - but none of them supported Gmail.

The closest I got to what I need is AOL's Alto Mail - but according to their website it supports max. 3 accounts.

I am willing to pay for a good tool which would suit my needs.

Comment: Do you look for a hosted solution, or would you host that yourself?

Comment: I would prefer a hosted one, although I am happy to try both :)

Comment: You can use whatever webmail client you want in combination with fetchmail / imapsync. I don't know about Google's calendar, but that should work for mail seamless.

Answer (score 1):

**[IQTELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQTELL)** was a productivity app that allowed users to manage email. It aimed to be an “Everything in One Place” hosted solution.

- **Emails:** sync Gmail, Exchange, iCloud, IMAP & POP3
- **Calendars:** Gmail, Exchange and iCloud  calendars
- Contacts: sync Google contacts
- Task management focused on the GTD (Getting Things Done) method ([what's that?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/a/123)).
- Project management
- Integration with Evernote

Comment: Seems the link doesn't load. Is the project dead?

Comment: @kenorb Apparently. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQTELL